# Get nodes of XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this Xml

```
<Content xmlns="uuid:28a55566-8657-4c56-9c44-">
    <Image xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/images/" xlink:title="albums_4" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></Image>
    <Title>Europe</Title>
</Content>
```

And I want to get each node data. The result should be for image node for example:

```
<Image xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/images/" xlink:title="albums_4" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></Image>
```

and `<Title>Europe</Title>` for Title node.

My C# code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(Xml);
                XNamespace ns = xDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()
var image = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Image").Single().Value; //it returns ""
```

Answer (score 0):

`Value` property in that particular usage returns what between the `Image` tags, that's why you got empty string. To get XML markup of the `Image` node you need to call `.ToString()` instead :

```
var image = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Image").Single().ToString();
```